# Google Assistant keeps giving an error after connected to IFTTT

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, ifttt

I have got an error issue.

Every time I say OK Google it answers with:

> Something went wrong, try again in a few seconds

or

> There was a glitch

Now my Raspberry assist does not do anything anymore.....

I searched the web and saw there was an issue involving this some time ago after an update of Philips Hue. But I do not have any Hue's around. So that is not it.

This happened after I added some recipes on IFTTT that connected to Google Assistant.

Anybody else getting this error?

Luc

Comment: Can you clarify what hardware you're seeing this problem with?

Answer (score 0):

Self fulfilling prophecy.

After a day without any action from my side it suddenly started working again. Maybe IFTTT had to do some cleanup overnight and that ended a loop. I really do not know what caused it to start working again.

So the solution to this problem (for now) seems to just have some patience.

Luc